# Missing production environment in package.json, svelte/pm2

Tags: node.js, svelte, pm2, sveltekit

I want to deploy my svelte app using pm2.

When I execute `pm2 deploy production setup`, I get this error:

> production environment is not defined in package.json file

How can I define the production environment? My package.json looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "module",
    "name": "myapp-frontend",
    "version": "0.2",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev --port 3000",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "production": "vite build --mode production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "next",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "prettier": "^2.4.1",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.4.0",
        "sass": "^1.49.4",
        "svelte": "^3.44.0",
        "svelte-dnd-action": "^0.9.9",
        "svelte-media": "^0.1.5",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.7.4",
        "svelte-scrollto": "^0.2.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "cookie": "^0.4.1",
        "date-and-time": "^2.3.1",
        "dayjs": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
        "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
        "svelte-chartjs": "^1.1.1",
        "svelte-intl-precompile": "^0.8.0",
        "svelte-select": "^5.0.0-beta.30"
    }
}
```

I added the "production" to scripts as a first try to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/) seems to state that you need a separate configuration file:

> Note: make sure the application configuration file in the local folder is named either ecosystem.config.js or pm2.config.js, so you don’t need to type the configuration filename for each command.

With example:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    script: 'api.js',
  }, {
    script: 'worker.js'
  }],
   
  // Deployment Configuration
  deploy : {
    production : {
       "user" : "ubuntu",
       "host" : ["192.168.0.13", "192.168.0.14", "192.168.0.15"],
       "ref"  : "origin/master",
       "repo" : "git@github.com:Username/repository.git",
       "path" : "/var/www/my-repository",
       "post-deploy" : "npm install"
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that with pm2 5.2.2 it only supports `ecosystem.config.js` and ignores `pm2.config.js`

With `pm2.config.js` I got the "production environment is not defined in package.json file" error.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the command as follows:

```bash
$ pm2 deploy <configuration_file> <environment> <command>
```

for example:

```bash
$ pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js production setup
```